# Inserting into a 1:1 reletationship

Tags: oracle, sql-insert

I have two tables. Tables A and B, each has a primary key that is autoincremented and foreign must not be null. Both tables are in a 1:1 relationship.

So, for every record in A there must be a B.

What I can't get working is the inserting into such tables. The error I get is "parent key not found".

I'm new to oracle, so thanks for helping.

Here is a screen of ER:
[image]

Here's my insert:

```
INSERT ALL
INTO NASTAVENI_TARIFU (ZADANI_D, ID_OBJEDNAVKY, ID_DODATKU, ID_TARIF, ID_NABIDKY) VALUES (TO_DATE('2018-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ), 1, SQ_SMLUVNI_DODATEK.nextval, 2, NULL)
INTO SMLUVNI_DODATKY (PROLONGACE_D,ID_NASTAVENI_TARIFU) VALUES (TO_DATE('2019-12-22', 'yyyy-mm-dd' ), SQ_NASTAVENI_TARIFU.currval)
SELECT * FROM DUAL
```

Here are the definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE nastaveni_tarifu (
    id_nastaveni_tarifu   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    zadani_d              DATE NOT NULL,
    id_objednavky         INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_dodatku            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_tarif              INTEGER NOT NULL,
    id_nabidky            INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE smluvni_dodatky (
    id_dodatku            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    prolongace_d          DATE NOT NULL,
    id_nastaveni_tarifu   INTEGER NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE smluvni_dodatky
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dodatek_nast_tarifu FOREIGN KEY ( id_nastaveni_tarifu )
        REFERENCES nastaveni_tarifu ( id_nastaveni_tarifu );

ALTER TABLE nastaveni_tarifu
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_nast_tarifu_dodatek FOREIGN KEY ( id_dodatku )
        REFERENCES smluvni_dodatky ( id_dodatku );

CREATE SEQUENCE sq_nastaveni_tarifu START WITH 1 MINVALUE 1 NOCACHE ORDER;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr$ntpreinsert BEFORE
    INSERT ON nastaveni_tarifu
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.id_nastaveni_tarifu IS NULL )
BEGIN
    :new.id_nastaveni_tarifu := sq_nastaveni_tarifu.nextval;
END;

CREATE SEQUENCE sq_smluvni_dodatek START WITH 1 MINVALUE 1 NOCACHE ORDER;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER tr$sdpreinsert BEFORE
    INSERT ON smluvni_dodatky
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN ( new.id_dodatku IS NULL )
BEGIN
    :new.id_dodatku := sq_smluvni_dodatek.nextval;
END;
```

... I'm starting to hate Oracle, this shouldn't be that hard :(

Comment: *"I cant get working"* isn't helpful. You should tell us the exact error message you get with the insert. Also, you should add table definitions as **plain-text** and not using images or ER diagram.

Comment: You have a circular foreign key reference which is a bad database design. One workaround for that  is to use `deferrable` while creating the constraints. But, a recommended solution is to revisit the design and come up with a better one without circular references.

Comment: I dont get it...The desired outcome is that with every A there must be a single B. Thats the client demand, all I want is the foreign keys to enforce that. There is no way to insert into oracle those two records like in a transaction or something?

Comment: Yeah as  @KaushikNayak stated, why not put all the data in one table? What is the reason to split it up into 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned, this is a bad design as there's circular reference between two tables.

The problem with your `insert all` statement is that there's no way the  second `into` clause could see  `SQ_NASTAVENI_TARIFU.nextval` as it can get initialised only when the statement as a whole is completed.

Even if you convert this to 2 insert statements, it wouldn't work because there's no way you could ensure to have a row in one table when the value is dependent on other in each case and also the foreign key columns are declared `not null`.

Either you define them as `NULL` and try to  first insert nulls and then update it or use a [Deferred Constraints](https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/constraint-checking-updates) as a **workaround** only.

```
ALTER TABLE smluvni_dodatky
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_dodatek_nast_tarifu FOREIGN KEY ( id_nastaveni_tarifu )
        REFERENCES nastaveni_tarifu ( id_nastaveni_tarifu ) 
    deferrable initially deferred;


ALTER TABLE nastaveni_tarifu
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_nast_tarifu_dodatek FOREIGN KEY ( id_dodatku )
        REFERENCES smluvni_dodatky ( id_dodatku ) deferrable initially deferred;
```

Now, there's another problem with your second Trigger, unless the primary key of the table `smluvni_dodatky` generated using the sequence `sq_smluvni_dodatek` can store the same value which was insert into `nastaveni_tarifu`, the constancy can't be maintained.

Hence in your Trigger `tr$sdpreinsert`, change the assignment expression to this

```
:new.id_dodatku := sq_smluvni_dodatek.currval;
```

Now, running both inserts as separate statements like this would work because the **constraint checking is not done until a**  **`commit` is issued.**

```
  INSERT   INTO nastaveni_tarifu (
          zadani_d,id_objednavky,id_dodatku,id_tarif,id_nabidky
     ) VALUES (
          TO_DATE('2018-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'), 1,sq_smluvni_dodatek.NEXTVAL, 2,NULL
     ) ;
 INSERT INTO smluvni_dodatky (
          prolongace_d,id_nastaveni_tarifu
     ) VALUES (
          TO_DATE('2019-12-22','yyyy-mm-dd'),sq_nastaveni_tarifu.currval);
commit;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8574aaf572307ece5513c3c7501a9dfa)